# Change a CSS button into a star image?

Tags: css, image, button

I want to know how I can change a normal default grey HTML button into an image using CSS.

This is the image I want to change into:

```
button.star {
    background-image: url(img/star.jpg); 
}
```

[image]

This is the image I'm using. It's for favoriting an item. Thanks :)

Is this the way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's just some random image from imgur, but basic concept. If there's no content in the button make sure you set the height/width otherwise it won't stretch to fit the button.

### As a background

```
button {
    background: url('http://imgur.com/I0EwG.png') transparent;
    height: 48px;
    width: 45px;
    border: none;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/robert/Wzu2S/

### In the button

HTML

```
<button><img src='http://imgur.com/I0EwG.png' /></button>​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

CSS

```
button {
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: transparent;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/robert/DjYmR/

Comment: how come when i do the css from an external file it deosnt work, but when i do it in the html page, it works whats the problem

Comment: Make sure you don't have anything overriding your CSS. An external sheet is going to have lower priority over inline CSS or any CSS declared on the html file.

Comment: no everything is done externally, this is the  inline css that i have? its confusing me lol

Comment: Do you have a live example up I can look at?

Comment: im going to put the whole css file in jsfiddle for is that alright http://jsfiddle.net/DjYmR/4/

Comment: Well that'll be the same as you having it in the HTML document. I was hoping for the link to the web page where you're having the trouble. Without that I'm only guessing that the problem is that it's not finding the image at `img/avatar.jpg`. See if an absolute URL resolves the issue.

Comment: your so right, thanks, sorry for being so dumb, i need to wake up :)) lol i wish i can give you two right answers!! cheers

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed :)

`background-image` will happily take a `url()` statement. If you have a bunch of `background` properties they can be condensed into just one `background` clause.

Eg.
`background-image: url('img/img.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-color: #5500ff;`
would turn into
`background: url('img/img.png') no-repeat #5500ff;`

Comment: thanks i put that, and i did this  `<input type="button" id="star" value="favorite">`, but its not showing

Comment: what you have done is use the class selector (`.`), but you gave the `<input>` an ID, not a class. Change `id="star"` to `class="star"`, or change the `.` for a `#` in the .CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is wrong.

`button.star` means an element of type `button` with a className of *star*

I suggest you try

```
#star {
  /* styles */
}
```

or

```
input#star {
  /* styles */
}
```

or just use the button element instead of input. Make sure you make it `type="button"` so the form will not post in IE.